# traceroute does not show the network my public ip is in

Tags: routing, traceroute

I retrieve my public ip and whois it:

```
whois $(wget -qO- ipinfo.io | grep -w ip | sed 's/"//g;s/://g;s/,//g;s/ip//g;s/^.*[ \t]//g')
```

my public ip:

```
79.116.123.39
```

whois result:

```
[...]
79.116.123.0 - 79.116.123.255
[...]
route:          79.116.0.0/16
```

then I traceroute to google.com

```
 1  _gateway (192.168.0.1)  6.002 ms  5.973 ms  5.958 ms
 2  172.19.217.49 (172.19.217.49)  49.053 ms  49.043 ms  52.209 ms
 3  172.24.1.161 (172.24.1.161)  55.486 ms  70.018 ms  69.978 ms
 4  81.196.118.208 (81.196.118.208)  73.225 ms  73.213 ms  73.244 ms
 5  91.232.81.211 (91.232.81.211)  73.189 ms 74.125.119.226 (74.125.119.226)  73.177 ms  73.162 ms
 6  108.170.253.241 (108.170.253.241)  73.150 ms 108.170.253.225 (108.170.253.225)  62.935 ms 108.170.253.241 (108.170.253.241)  62.905 ms
 7  142.251.51.143 (142.251.51.143)  69.595 ms 142.251.51.141 (142.251.51.141)  44.583 ms  52.464 ms
 8  mad41s14-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.200.142)  39.579 ms  52.352 ms  58.850 ms
```

Although all nodes the packets are going through are visible, at any moment they go through the network my public is in, why?
shouldnt there be at least one router/node inside my public ip network?

thanx folks!

Answer (score 2):

The NAT gateway handling your public IP address, as well as the next-hop router beyond it, also have other IP addresses they use. Routers always have multiple IP addresses. As long as they send their ICMP Time Exceeded messages from IP addresses that can reach your device, everything's fine. There's no rule saying routers must send ICMP error messages from certain addresses based on what the offending packet's source or destination IP address was.

Answer (score 1):

Digi Spain Telecom owns more than one IP range.
You may see the current list of IPs on
[ipinfo.io](https://ipinfo.io/AS57269).

Your trace enters a known range of Digi Spain Telecom only at
`91.232.81.211`.
To get there it passes through another ISP at `81.196.118.208`
which is RCS & RDS Business in Romania.

All the IPs that start with `172.*` seem to be local IPs inside
some NAT network. These IP Addresses fall within the
Internet's Private or Reserved IP Address Space so cannot be used
as internet public IPs..

The fact is that the hops shown by `traceroute` show the
path that an IP packet follows on a routed (layer 3) network.
Routers will show up, but switches will not.

In more detail, switches that are layer 2 devices pass Ethernet frames
using the MAC addresses. Some switches are "layer 3 switches"
and are able to function as routers,
but even a layer 3 switch will not necessarily show up in traceroute.

If the traffic within the ISP local network uses layer 2 or 3 switches
that do not show up in traceroute, this may explain why your traceroute
is missing nodes within this network and you're only
seeing nodes after the traceroute packet exits it.

It seems further that your ISP may be sub-contracting another ISP
called RCS & RDS Business, which further adds to the confusion.

Comment: L3 switches that are set up to act as routers should show up in traceroute as well, checking TTL is a mandatory part of "acting as a router". It's *somewhat* normal for ISPs to use private IP addresses for their internal routers – that doesn't prevent the routers from carrying public IP address traffic (i.e. NAT doesn't need to be involved), anything can be routed through anything.